# Doing the tutorial...enums dropdown values are set to same text as display..shouldn't they be rendered as integers

Tags: enums, abp

I'm testing out the tutorial in preparation of a project.  I've noticed that the dropdown that is rendered for an Enum field has both the Localization text in both the value and text.  Should it not have the enum integer value for value and the localization text for the text part?  Am i missing a configuration setting?

See code below

```
    <select class="custom-select form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Status field is required." id="InvCategory_Status" name="InvCategory.Status"><option selected="selected" value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Same issue with:
https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/10167

You have to add resources with Key `Enum:{EnumType}.{EnumName}`

In your situation, let's say you have an enum like that:

```cs
public enum Confirmation
{
    Yes,
    No
}
```

And add resources of those values:

```json
"Enum:Confirmation.Yes" : "Yes",
"Enum:Confirmation.No" : "No"
```